# Export MYSQL rows into several txt files

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MYSQL database with 50.000 rows. Each row represents an article. I want the value of the column with they name "articletext" to be split into 50.000 files. One file for each row. I'm new to MYSQL so I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: This probably can't be done with mySQL alone. Can you use a programming language?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can create a small java application that connects to the database. Does that sound like the best solution?

Comment: you will certainly need another language to do the procedural part - sql is not a file creation language it is a query language.

Comment: yes @Peter, you can use java.  connect to the database, write a select statement to loop over the 50,000 rows, create a FILE object, and write the values to it for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created this small java application to solve the problem.

```
        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Opening connection");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/articles", "username", "password");

        String query = "Select title,articletext from articles";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String title = rs.getString(1);
            String text = rs.getString(2);

            try {
                FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(title + ".txt");

                BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
                out.write(text);
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Closing connection");
        con.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

And I propose my solution using Python:

```
import MySQLdb

def write_to_file(with_name, write_this):
    with_name = str(with_name)
    with open(with_name, "w") as F:
        F.write(write_this)

db = MySQLdb.connect(
   host="localhost",    # hostname, usually localhost
   user="andi",         # your username
   passwd="passsword",  # your password
   db="db_name",        # name of the database
   charset = "utf8",    # encoding
   use_unicode = True
) 

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("select id, description from SOME_TABLE")

for row in cur.fetchall() :
    write_to_file(row[0], row[1].encode('utf8'))
```

where `row[0]` will map to `id`, `row[1]` will map to `description`